# Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: load_library[1098]: Library '/system/lib/libhoudini.so' not found

Tags: android

I updated Android Studio to 3.0.0 and Gradle to 3.0.0

After run my app on emulator Genymotion (API 16-19) crashed.

**Error:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
                      at android.support.v4.app.SupportActivity.<init>(SupportActivity.java:68)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityGingerbread.<init>(BaseFragmentActivityGingerbread.java:37)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.<init>(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:29)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.<init>(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:30)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.<init>(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.<init>(AppCompatActivity.java:61)
                      at com.myapp.start.BaseActivity.<init>(BaseActivity.java:37)
                      at com.myapp.start.StartActivity.<init>(StartActivity.java:40)
                      at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                   Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: load_library[1098]: Library '/system/lib/libhoudini.so' not found
```

Native methods in my app not using. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your advanced profiling Run-->Edit Configurations.. --> Profiling Tab 
 --> Uncheck (Enable advanced profiling)